# JQuery .text() method outputting garbled text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've been having a strange issue with JQuery's .text() method. What I have right now is some JS code that generates a random phrase from a few banks of random words, which I believe has no problem (it basically just produces a string). When you click a link in the browser, that link's text is replaced by a random phrase produced by the random phrase generator. So far, there is nothing wrong with the generated random phrase. However, it tends to garble the text behind it:

[image: Garbled Text]

It seems that the browser is having difficulty when pushing text to the next line, causing it to overlap with the text that was already there. 
When I highlight the paragraph, it "resets" correctly and it's fine until I try clicking the link again. If I zoom in or out, it seems like it's fine until I return to 100% zoom. If I make the text font size smaller, it seems to work fine too.

Here is the Javascript code:

```
//Initially get random phrase and display it on the page
getRandomPhrase();
$('#phrase').text(finalPhrase.new);

//On click, get the random phrase and display it on the page
$('#phrase').click(function () {
    getRandomPhrase();
    $('#phrase').text(finalPhrase.new);
});
```

Here is the HTML tag that I'm trying to replace:

```
<a title="Click!" href="#about" id="phrase">(the random phrase should be in here)</a>
```

The tag is in the middle of a paragraph of text. If anyone has any idea how I could fix this that would be great!

Edit: Here's all of the CSS, don't know what the problem could be. I'm using this on top of Bootstrap:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab);
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background-color: #FFF7E4;
    font-size: 14px;
}

h1 {}

hr {
    border-color: #9A9A9A;
}

#name {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #DB1C00;
}

#header {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    background-color: #CCC6A6;
}

#about {
    font-size: 20px;
}

#phrase {
    color: #DB1C00;
}
```

Comment: We are gonna need your css.

Comment: Definitely a CSS issue.

Comment: I've added the CSS, I'm using it on top of a 3-column Bootstrap theme, so hopefully there's no issue there...

Comment: @mochination Can you reproduce the problem on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @SergeSeredenko No, it works perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/rpuwsnsg/ (click the red link)

Comment: Okay, I think I've fixed the problem. I'm going to commit to github and see what occurs...

Comment: @SergeSeredenko I've fixed the issue, but I don't know how...I posted an answer and maybe you could enlighten me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just managed to fix the problem. The solution is very strange, though.
I should've added more HTML to the original post.

Here is a basic view of the frontend HTML:

```
<div id="about">blah blah blah about me stuff 
    <a title="Click!" href="#about" id="phrase">(the random phrase should be in here)</a>
</div>
```

I had sent the link in the tag to go to #about, which did not seem wrong at all. (The reason I did this was because the user needed to be able to click on the link and stay there to see the result). I changed the href to #phrase, thus linking the link to itself:

```
<div id="about">blah blah blah about me stuff 
    <a title="Click!" href="#phrase" id="phrase">(the random phrase should be in here)</a>
</div>
```

This fixed the whole garbled text issue somehow. My hypothesis is that linking to the entire div was somehow not allowing it to reset properly, or that it was caching the div's original content in some way. Anyways, if someone could properly explain why this works that would be great haha. If anybody has a good explanation, please let me know! It's a really weird solution and I have no idea why it works (or why there was a problem in the first place!